# Some errors when I tried to get JSON data from a server

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, extjs

I was using jQuery's getJSON method and a method in Extjs to get some json data from server.

The Javascript code is put on apache2 on server A and the web service is put on tomcat7 on server A. But when I use host B to visit the javascript, and the a method in javascript code calls the web service. the request is made from host B to server A, right?

But I get an error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.5.107:8080/restful/product/all/?callback=?&_dc=1384439969320&page=1&start=0&limit=25. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.5.107' is therefore not allowed access.
```

And I have to add the

```
?callback=?
```

to my url.

But I get another error called "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : " with my jQuery code. I googled this and most of the persons' suggestion is to remove the callback. But I have to use it, or I cannot get the JSON data.

Here's my code using jQuery:

```
$.getJSON('http://192.168.5.115:8080/restful/standard/id/' + id, function(data) {
        console.log('old data:\n');
        console.log(data); // use data as a generic object
        oldObj = data;
        var newObj = Object.keys(oldObj).map(function(k) {
            return { key: k, value: oldObj[k] };
        });

        console.log('new data:\n');
        console.log(newObj); // use data as a generic object
    });
```

And even I add the callback parameter. The code in Extjs still get the first error.

Here's my Extjs code:

```
// create the data store
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'Product',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url : 'http://192.168.5.115:8080/restful/product/all/?callback',
            reader: {
                type: 'json'
            }
        }
    });
```

I have tried to fix his for three days and got nothing. I really wish someone can help me solve it.

Comment: Without answering your actual question, you may like to read over http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing, and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP for some comprehensive general background.

Comment: You did not make it clear that your REST service is returning JSONP data. If not you'd better try enabling CORS instead of trying jsonp http://stackoverflow.com/a/5753269/1236044

Comment: @jbl You are right. But I have tried multiple way to add the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header on the server's response. like add a filter in /etc/tomcat7/web.xml. add the header in the return statement in java. But still cannot work

Comment: @apsillers I have read these. I think I have added all the support for CORS, but I still get the error. And now I want to try to add the callback. But get new error

Comment: Ext call seems different on this page http://www.objis.com/formationextjs/lib/extjs-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.data.proxy.JsonP.html with a jsonp type instead of ajax, and special properties for callback handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to "try the callback", you must use a proxy of type 'jsonp', not 'ajax'.

The callback param will be added automatically by the proxy, however your server will have to **process** it, that is use the actual callback name demanded by the client.

[This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16739785/1387519) will give you a complete example both for client, and for server (in the answer).